# How extract pictures from an big image in python

Tags: python, opencv, vision

[image: Sample google image]

There is a big image of this one.
I want to extract only rectangular pictures in a large image.
Big images are of poor quality. So you can not use only specific RGB, and the background may not be white.

How I did it

- Threshold image to separate background area and photo part.
  The problem is that can not fix the threshold value for each picture color at random (the background is white but the picture is a light gray background close to white).
- Use the OpenCV2 Contour Area to find the rectangle.
  The problem is that the color of each picture is random, which makes it impossible to find a rectangular area.

How can I cut out pictures?

Comment: You can try to do something like: 1) convert to greyscale, 2) anything that is white will be black and everything non white will be white 3) do find contours 4) each contour == 1 picture

Comment: Maybe try Fred's (@fmw42) multicrop. He'll tell you all about it and licensing etc... http://fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php

Comment: @api55 I tried everything I did.

Comment: @MarkSetchell If the image is close to the image. it recognizes two or three images as one image.It does not make sense to change the parameters according to the image. That is currently implemented state.

Answer (score 5):

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
gradient = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)

contours = cv2.findContours(gradient, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]

for cnt in contours:
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255))
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks. But This method recognizes the images as one when they are close to each other. https://imgur.com/LF16yQG

Comment: @Nox10009 That's a little unfair - and actually implies your sample image wasn't very representative...

Comment: @Mark Setchell Yes, I know.. Some images are 2 pixels in spacing and jpeg quality is 60%.... So It's driving me crazy! Thank you for your attention.